# AJAX/PHP Element Removal Tutorial

Tags: php, ajax

My goals are threefold:

1. load terms.php, a page of links (glossary terms), dynamically into index.php's div.sidepanel using AJAX. the glossary terms (links) are housed as a list in div.glossary in the loaded terms.php.
2. load span.definition1, into div.glossary, next to the glossary term it defines, again with AJAX. span.definition1 is a php string that is generated when the first glossary term in clicked.
3. load span.definition2 into div.glossary, next to the glossary term it defines, and simultaneously, **remove** span.definition1 when the link that loads definition2 is clicked.

I have succeeded in each of these three goals up to the point of removing the previously loaded definition when a new glossary term is clicked. Is there a tutorial that explains how this is done? I have provided a short excerpt from terms.php that can be loaded with a click of the Glossary link on my site at http://postmaterial.org/index.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure without the code.  But you should be able to use `element.removeChild(child);` where element is the parent element and child is the node that you want to delete.  So:

```
<div id="parent">
   <span id="word1">Word (click me)</span>
   <span id="definition1">I am a definition, I should be deleted when necessary</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function removedefinition() {
   var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
   var child = document.getElementById('definition1');
   parent.removeChild(child);
 }
 </script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild

Comment: Thanks very much Sam. This issue has been a lesson for me. Javascript becomes more interesting each day. And AJAX is awesome!

Comment: The most recent project I am working on is the first time I have really extensively used Javascript.  It does continue to become more interesting.  AJAX is a life saver too.